# Cocos2dx Crash - Version 3.17.2

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, game-development, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

how to solve these cocos2dx game crashes?

following is the backtrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method “void 
android.content.pm.PackageManager$OnChecksumsReadyListener.onChecksumsReady(java.util.List)”
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager$2.onChecksumsReady(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1016)
at android.content.pm.IOnChecksumsReadyListener$Stub.onTransact(IOnChecksumsReadyListener.java:87)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1220)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1179)
```

this is from the play console crash. appear in cocos2dx 3.17.2 game.

```
[libMyGame.so] cocos2d::Sequence::update(float)
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.company.DemoGame <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000002ac08c  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so
  #01  pc 0x00000000002e0f7d  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (cocos2d::Sequence::update(float)+278)
  #02  pc 0x00000000002e0f23  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (cocos2d::Sequence::update(float)+188)
  #03  pc 0x00000000002e0f23  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (cocos2d::Sequence::update(float)+188)
  #04  pc 0x00000000002e0a5d  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (cocos2d::ActionInterval::step(float)+112)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000392e93  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (cocos2d::ActionManager::update(float)+94)
  #06  pc 0x00000000002e539b  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (std::__ndk1::function<void (float)>::operator()(float) const+18)
  #07  pc 0x000000000035d87b  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (cocos2d::Scheduler::update(float)+94)
  #08  pc 0x000000000034ff97  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (cocos2d::Director::drawScene()+42)
  #09  pc 0x00000000003514a5  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (cocos2d::Director::mainLoop()+44)
  #10  pc 0x000000000006cb37  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/oat/arm/base.odex (org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeDeleteBackward [DEDUPED]+94)
  #11  pc 0x000000000006da4b  /data/app/com.company.DemoGame-wFz3_4vUXhkLB6m5XdqJJQ==/oat/arm/base.odex (org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.onDrawFrame+210)
  #12  pc 0x00000000009d7929  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun+3040)
  #13  pc 0x00000000009d876d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run+180)
  #14  pc 0x000000000042e975  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #15  pc 0x0000000000401821  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+224)
  #16  pc 0x00000000000a82b9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+136)
  #17  pc 0x000000000035e9cd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
  #18  pc 0x000000000035f725  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+320)
  #19  pc 0x0000000000381203  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+866)
  #20  pc 0x0000000000064d55  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
  #21  pc 0x000000000001ec41  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+24)
```

Comment: I really wonder which code or workflow you have written makes you face this error. and can you please use a separate code block so that your code can be indexed properly? this 2nd part is forum rules . thx

Comment: Brother, that is the only play console logs. I have simply used AdMob for ads

Comment: Instead of all the `please help me` texts, you should have explained what code causes this, what have you already checked so far etc...

Comment: you all are right. but which code I have to post here I don't know because it is a play console log. how I will get the things of the crash reason from all CPP files?  hope you can understand me. basically backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in near the Sequence::create(.... CC_CALLBACK_..) in your code.

Comment: okay, I will check. thank you for your response. there are two crashes in my cocos2dx version 3.7.2 game. so a problem in the cocos2dx library right brother?